# Getting error on joining tables in rails 6

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have following models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Roleable
end

class Volunteer < User
  default_scope {joins(:roles).where("roles.name=?", 'volunteer')}
  has_many :calendar_day_requests
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :roles_users, foreign_key: :role_id
end

class CalendarDayRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :volunteer, optional: true
end
```

and in my `Roleable` concern I have

```
module Roleable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: :roles_users, foreign_key: :user_id
  end
end
```

I can do `Volunteer.joins(:calendar_day_requests)` but when I try to do `CalendarDayRequest.joins(:volunteer)` I get following output with error

```
CalendarDayRequest Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "calendar_day_requests".* FROM "calendar_day_requests" INNER JOIN "users" ON (roles.name='volunteer') AND "users"."id" = "calendar_day_requests"."volunteer_id" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "roles")
LINE 1: ...OM "calendar_day_requests" INNER JOIN "users" ON (roles.name...
```

What am I doing wrong here Please let me know if any further information required.
schema for `clanedar_day_requests` table is

```
create_table "calendar_day_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "request_id", null: false
    t.bigint "calendar_day_id", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "volunteer_id"
    t.bigint "assigned_by_id"
    t.bigint "vehicle_id"
    t.datetime "pickup_date_time"
    t.boolean "notification_sent_for_24_hours", default: true
    t.boolean "notification_sent_for_3_hours", default: true
    t.index ["assigned_by_id"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_assigned_by_id"
    t.index ["calendar_day_id"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_calendar_day_id"
    t.index ["notification_sent_for_24_hours"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_notification_sent_for_24_hours"
    t.index ["notification_sent_for_3_hours"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_notification_sent_for_3_hours"
    t.index ["pickup_date_time"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_pickup_date_time"
    t.index ["request_id"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_request_id"
    t.index ["vehicle_id"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_vehicle_id"
    t.index ["volunteer_id"], name: "index_calendar_day_requests_on_volunteer_id"
end
```

Comment: Can you share columns in `calendar_days_requests` table? Are you able to do `CalendarDayRequest.first.volunteers`? 

For `belongs_to` association to work, `volunteer_id` must exist in `calendar_days_requests` table.

Comment: @PrabinPoudel I have updated the question with schema and yes I can do CalendarDayRequest.first.volunteer